# Little envelope next to method's name in class designer (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio

I am curious. What is the meaning of a little envelope next to a method's name? I am using the class designer of Visual Studio 2010.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please post an image so we know what exactly you mean.

Comment: [Like these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: Just add them up from bzlm's link.  The diamond means it is a method, the envelope means it is internal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe.aspx) bzlm posted in his comment does contain the envelope:

> [image: envelope] | Internal. Accessible only from this component.

It is one of the signal icons:

> The following signal icons apply to all the previous icons and indicate their accessibility.

So, the `QBar` method is internal.

Comment: In my screenshot is more yellowish :p, that is why I thought it wasn't there :P